# Suppress script error in webbrowser control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, suppress-warnings

I get multiple script errors with the following details:

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page
line: 13
Char: 3
Error: 'UI' is undefined
Code: 0
URL: about:blank

Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
Yes No
```

The line and char values change. I've already tried setting:

```
 WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

I've also tried the method in the example code on this MSDN page:
[WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed(v=vs.110).aspx)

I'm compleatly lost on what else I could do to suppress these errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm working in VB.Net.

Comment: Are you setting `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` before you load any content into the control? (I note that the URL is `about:blank`, but there is no script in the black page... IE's error reporting isn't the greatest).

Comment: I am. I've used that property before without problem. Is there anything that can make it not work?